# Rails log message: cache: [POST /action] invalidate, pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm running rails 3 with jruby and trinidad, and I keep seeing these log messages:

```
INFO http-bio-3001-exec-15 jruby.rack - cache: [POST /something] invalidate, pass
```

What exactly does this mean? Also, the code in the controller is also never run. Is this an issue with caching?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever Rails receives a POST request, it performs some security checks to make sure the request is "valid". The checks are performed by parsing [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) authenticity tokens which MUST be submitted along with the form in a POST request.

If you're not able to edit the form that is making the request to your rails app, you can skip the check on controller-by-controller basis:

```
class Foo < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
```

or you can also choose to do so for a specific method in the controller:

```
class Foo < ApplicationController
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:create]
```

You can read about it [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html)

Answer (score 2):

cache: [POST /something] invalidate, pass

This is saying a POST request was issued and the invalidate, pass means that a cache couldn't be used for this type of request. You'll get the invalidate, pass for any change request (POST, PUT, DELETE etc)